# Help Converting a Java Crypto class over to Apex Crypto

Tags: apex, java, crypto

I have a java class for generating a token and I am struggling on converting it to apex.  Below is the code.  Any pointers would be appreciated!

Here are the two methods in the java class that get called and the code in main that invokes them:

```
public static final String PROVISION_TOKEN = "provision";
private static final long EPOCH_SECONDS = 62167219200l;
private static final String DELIM = "\0";


public static String generateProvisionToken(String key, String jid, String expires, String vcard) throws NumberFormatException {
    String payload = String.join(DELIM, PROVISION_TOKEN, jid, expires, vcard);
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(
            (String.join(DELIM, payload, HmacUtils.hmacSha384Hex(key, payload))).getBytes()
    ));
}

public static String calculateExpiry(String expires) throws NumberFormatException {
    long expiresLong = 0l;
    long currentUnixTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    expiresLong = Long.parseLong(expires);
    return ""+(EPOCH_SECONDS + currentUnixTimestamp + expiresLong);
}
```

Code in main:

```
generateProvisionToken(key, userName + "@" + appID, expires, vCard);
```

This is the apex I tried but am not having any luck generating the expected token:

```
public String generateToken() {

    String token;
    String username = UserInfo.getName().deleteWhitespace();
    String developerKey = 'myKey';
    String appId = 'myApp';
    Long EPOCH_SECONDS = 62167219200L;
    String delim = '\\0';
    Double expires = Math.floor(Datetime.Now().getTime() / 1000) + 86400 + EPOCH_SECONDS;

    String jid = userName + '@' + appID;
    String body = delim+'provision'+jid+expires;


    token = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA384', Blob.valueOf(body), Blob.valueOf(developerKey)));

    Blob nb = Blob.valueOf(delim+body+token);

    String serialized = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(nb);


    return serialized;
}
```